# Divs are not alligned into one line using display:inline

Tags: html, css

I got submission form generated with Cobalt 8 Joomla plugin. It has 4 fields: 2 textboxes and 2 selects and each of them is stored in separate div so on the next line. But I need them somehow to be placed on the same line.

I've already tried setting **display:inline** to these divs but this didn't solve an issue. Looks like that some other styles are breaking my display.

As far as there are a lot of other css files in Joomla I cannot create JSFiddle, but here's the link to the problematic form: [Form with divs](http://cobold.byethost17.com/index.php/en/show-tests/submit/2-test/2-test)

I want 4 elements starting from **Test 1** label to be displayed in a single line: textbox, select, textbox, select.

I would be appreciated if someone could take a look into this form and explain me why is it failing when using **display:inline**

Comment: MySQL error on that page, why don't you recreate it on jsfiddle or as a snippet here?

Comment: @Shomz, try reloading the page. This is the problem of hosting. It happens now often :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still has some layout issues (due to your testing, I assume), but these two rules are crucial:

```
.control-group {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**Inline-block** ensures that those divs still have their paddings and margins while not being full blocks (not taking 100% of the width, thus forcing next non-block elements into new rows).

**Vertical-align**, as the name says, forces all those inline-blocks to be glued to the top of their parent element. You might not need it when you remove your test thing (like that label, a one or two more elements with added styles). But basically, it allows you to avoid this:

```
---   -----    
| |   |   |  ----
| |   |   |  |  |
| |   |   |  ----
---   -----
```

and have this instead:

```
---   -----  ----    
| |   |   |  |  |
| |   |   |  ----
| |   |   |  
---   -----
```

Note: those photo-realistic graphics represent div boxes.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. It really makes sense. But I've tried adding class ``TestClass`` to these divs with specified parameters but still it doesn't work. The result is still on the same page.

Comment: Ah, I see, you need to kill that left margin on them as well. You need to ensure that the width of all 4 elements (width + borders + margin actually) fits the parent. That huge left margin was taking a lot of space, forcing elements into new rows. This is the problematic rule you need to override: `.form-horizontal .controls {margin-left: 180px;}`

Comment: That's amazing! Works like a charm now! Thanks a lot, Shomz!